# Convert U08* buffer into U16*

Tags: c++, casting

I got `U08* _buffer` and I need to pass this parameter to function which gets `U16*`:

Function signature: `FunctionA(U16 offset, U16 * pInbuff)`

Trying to call it like this: `FunctionA(0, (U16*)(m->GetBuffer));`

Getting

```
warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'U32' to 'U16', possible loss of data
error C2220: warning treated as error- no 'object' file generated.
```

Do you know how to make the cast right?

Comment: Why do you think casting is the solution?

Comment: You forgot to post the warning that is being treated as an error.

Comment: This is the warning: warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'U32' to 'U16', possible loss of data

Comment: Any idea for a proper solution which is not cast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `U08` and `U16` are unsigned integral types of 8 and 16 bits wide respectively then the correct method of conversion depends on the exact data format in the buffer.

First, a simple cast is probably not the right solution even if the layout of data in the buffer is exactly right. Unless your `U08` buffer was originally a `U16*` buffer and was cast to `U08*` somewhere along the line then you can run into alignment problems, either crashes or just poor performance, from inappropriate casts. If this is the case then the solution is to get rid of that cast to `U08*` in the first place, rather than to add an additional cast back to `U16*`.

If the data layout in the `U08` buffer is correct for your desired `U16` buffer then instead of creating a `U08` buffer you should create a `U16` buffer to start with, if possible. If the code that populates the `U08` buffer cannot be changed to use a `U16` buffer then that may be one of the rare cases where casting is acceptable; create a `U16` buffer, cast to `U08*` to populate it, and then you can pass the `U16` buffer to your function without modification.

If you are not responsible for creating the buffer in the first place then you may need to create your own `U16` buffer, copy data from the `U08` buffer into the `U16` buffer (using std::memcpy or similar), and then using that `U16` buffer with `FunctionA`.

Secondly, if the layout of data in the `U08` buffer differs from the data layout in the expected `U16` buffer then you'll have to create your own `U16` buffer and convert the `U08` data.

---

Also, the error you show doesn't describe the actual problem; it just says you've configured the compiler to treat warnings as errors and that there's some warning. That's a good thing but you need to look at the warning to figure out what you need to fix to make the warning go away.

---

> warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'U32' to 'U16', possible loss of data

This warning has nothing to do with the code you showed, as far as I can tell. You're lucky you got a warning that prevented the code you show from silently compiling even though it's probably wrong. That's one of the reasons casts are a really bad idea; they can silence serious errors and hide bugs. You should not uses casts unless you really know what you're doing, and probably rarely even then.

The above warning is complaining about some code where a `U32` value is being assigned to a `U16` object. For example:

```
U32 a = 1000000;
U16 b = a;
```

Since `U32` has more valid values than `U16`, not all of those `U32` values can be converted to `U16`. Conversion of values of `U32` that cannot be represented by `U16` may have unexpected results. So you either need to avoid the conversion or make sure that you've accounted for those otherwise unexpected occurrences.

Comment: More likely, they are equivalents of uint8_t and uint16_t. But casting wouldn't be the answer there either.

Comment: This is the real error:

Comment: warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'U32' to 'U16', possible loss of data

Answer (score 0):

```
FunctionA(0, (U16*)(m->GetBuffer));
```

that should almost certainly be

```
FunctionA(0, (U16*)(m->GetBuffer()));
```

Unless, of course, `getBuffer` is a badly named pointer and not a function.

Answer (score 0):

If your types are integers where U08 is an unsigned byte and U16 is an unsigned 16-bit word then you can solve the problem by padding the data.  The following code should pad the data and allow you to pass the buffer as an array of unsigned 16-bit values.

```
int bufferSize;  // set this value with the actual buffer size
U16 wordBuffer= new U16[bufferSize];
U16 *wordBufferIndexer = wordBuffer;
U08 *byteBufferIndexer = byteBuffer;
for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; ++i)
{
    wordBufferIndexer = *(byteBufferIndexer++);
}

FunctionA(0, wordBuffer);
```